# Unable to set value for tags

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I'm unable to set an initial value for a select2 v4.0.1 instance; the select is being created with tags: true.

HTML:

```
<select id="tags" name="tags" class="form-control" multiple></select>
```

JS:

```
$('#tags').select2({'tags': true});
```

Tried with:

```
<select id="tags" name="tags" class="form-control" multiple>
<option selected>{{ tag }}</option>
</select>
```

and:
    $('#tags').select2({'tags': true});
    $('#tags').val(["test"]).change();

and other smaller variations, to no avail :'(

This documentation snippet seems to have a lead: https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#removed-initselection but is very confusing, I'm a new user of select2.

According to older posts, this is not an issue at all with the older select2 3 series, but it includes hidden input issues and other nasty stuff.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Answering myself :)

Found two viable slightly different ways:

1. Add static child `<option>` elements

   ```
   <select id="tags" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off">
   <option selected>test1</option>
   <option selected>test2</option>
   </select>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tags').select2({tags: true});
   </script>
   ```
2. Dynamically add child `<option>` elements, then trigger a change

   ```
   <select id="tags" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off"></select>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#tags').select2({tags: true});
   $('#tags').append("<option selected>test1</option><option selected>test2</option>").change();
   });
   </script>
   ```

The val() method works only for selecting an option, not for adding/removing options to a select multiple.